# How Can Load Page Without influence on master page?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, master-pages

I have MasterPage.master bellow

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="load page" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to load pages .aspx inside ContentPlaceHolder1 without load master page every time.
How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think update panel is what you are after.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

It will allow you to update the content using AJAX to avoid refreshing the outer content.

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <head runat="server">
               <title></title>
               <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
               </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
          </head>
          <body>
          <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <div>
               <asp:updatepanel ID="Updatepanel1" runat="server">
               <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
               </Triggers>
               <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
               </ContentTemplate>
               </asp:updatepanel>

               <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="load page" />

          </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I haven't been able to test this but it should give you an idea.

Button 1 should now trigger the update panel to refresh. You can also refresh the updatepanel programatically with

```
UpdatePanel1.Update()
```